# Graphics Pixel Index

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, pixel

I have an image with a white background i want to get the first pixel index of a  different color (Black).

```
public Element? GetFirstIndex(Image img)
{
  Color c = new();
  for(int i=0; i<300; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j <300; j++)
    {
      c = GetDominantColor(new(img), i, j, 1, 1);
      if (c.Name != "ffffffff") return new Element() { XPosition = j, YPosition = i, Heigh = 1, Width = 1 };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

this code is very slow

Answer (score 0):

I think that i have resolve my problem :
I split the code to 2 part one to find the 1st X of color index and the 2nd to find the first Y of color index

```
        public Element? GetFirstIndex(Image img)
    {
        Element? element = null;
        for(int i=0; i<img.Height; i++)
        {
            Color c = GetDominantColor(new(img), 0, i, img.Width, 1);
            if (c.Name != "ffffffff")
            {
                element = new Element() { XPosition = 0, YPosition = i, Heigh = 1, Width = 1 };
                break;
            }
        }
        if (element == null) return element;
        for(int i=0; i<img.Width; i++)
        {
            Color c = GetDominantColor(new(img), i, 0, 1, img.Height);
            if (c.Name != "ffffffff")
            {
                element = new Element() { XPosition = i, YPosition = element.YPosition, Heigh = 1, Width = 1 };
                break;
            }
        }
        return element;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are testing the entire image.  I might be wrong because it's not documented how GetDominantColor works.

Comment: Agreed, tis unclear; is it your intention to only test the leftmost column and topmost row?